# StreamCorruptedException for Server-Client app

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

My Server runs this code in a Thread, so that I can interact with the GUI while I am waiting for my client to connect.(I am only using 1 client and 1 server at the moment.)

```
@Override
public void run() {

    Socket client = null;
    MessageListener listener = null;

    try {
        client = server.accept();
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        listener = new MessageListener(ois);
        (new Thread(listener)).start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My Client runs this code once to connect to the server and fix the input/output streams:

```
try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        MessageListener listener = new MessageListener(ois);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
        (new Thread(listener)).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

MessageListener runs a thread to check for incomming messages.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        Message message = null;
        try {
            message = (Message) in.readObject();
            if (message != null) {
                System.out.println(message.getName());
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

However, when I launch my program, at first I can only send from Server to Client and not the other way around(I just cannot interact with the Client GUI).
Once I send the first message from Server to Client I receive the following error message:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 6F
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at com.jale.chat.iohandling.MessageListener.run(MessageListener.java:25)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Edit:** after I have gotten the first error message, I can only send from Client to Server(the sending actually works) but the Error messages keep spamming my console.

Line 25 of MessageListener:

```
message = (Message) in.readObject();
```

Haven't found anything on google/Stack Overflow, as the general Problem when getting a `StreamCorruptedException` seems to be when people open multiple `InputStreams` or `OutputStreams` for a single Socket, which I am however not doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have opened your Input/Output-Streams more than once. Try checking that the connect-Function gets only called once.

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing `ObjectOutputStreams` and then throwing them away. They should be passed to the constructor of `MessageListener` just like the `ObjectInputStreams,` so it has something valid per-client to write with. You can't possibly write correctly to the peer the way your code is now. Probably you are reusing an `ObjectOutputStream` for the wrong peer somewhere.

Those `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` variables you are creating should be local to the method, not members of the surrounding class. And in fact both those streams should be constructed in the `run()` method of the thread you are about to start, not inline in the `accept()` loop. Otherwise you risk blocking in the wrong place. And the `ObjectOutputStream` should always be constructed before the `ObjectInputStream`, to make deadlocks impossible.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, you must use identical class (with id) for both client/server sides. I've put my message mechanism into library that is used in both client/server projects. And besides, if I compile server/client, I compile all three projects ... Maybe this will help.

Comment: Not really, as I have only one project where I chose on launch wether to start it as server or client. Besides, I have the same problem when I am sending simple Strings.

Comment: This isn't a `serialVersionUID` problem, if that's what you're talking about so obscurely.